# How to assign column value based on partial string match from a different dataframe of a different length in R

Tags: r

Here is a minimally reproducible example:

```
Spike.ID <- c("230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 1_NOX", "230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 2_NOX", "230621_BGH_11 SPIKE 1_NOX", "230621_BGH_11 SPIKE 2_NOX")
SpikeConc <- c(4,11,17,12)

Spikes <- data.frame(Spike.ID, SpikeConc)

Sample.ID <- c("230621_BGH_03_NOX", "230621_BGH_11_NOX")
SampleConc <- c(7, 13)

Samples <-data.frame(Sample.ID, SampleConc)
```

What I am trying to do is to assign BOTH Spike 1 and Spike 2 rows from the Spikes dataframe the same value from the Samples dataframe by matching the ID's (note that they are an inexact match) such that the final product looks like this:

```
> Spikes
                   Spike.ID SpikeConc SampleConc
1 230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 1_NOX         4          7
2 230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 2_NOX        11          7
3 230621_BGH_11 SPIKE 1_NOX        17         13
4 230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 2_NOX        12         13
```

additionally, I am doing this dynamically in shiny, so the two data frames could both be 4 times longer and the ID's can be different (not across the two data frames, the similarity there is consistent, I just mean in general). I have tried using things like sapply and loops but have not been able to get anything to work due to the mismatched length of the dataframes...

Comment: You may be interested in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/fuzzyjoin.pdf

Comment: What is the rule to join rows by? Is it based on IDs or conc values? I can't figure out a rule based on the IDs from your example.

Comment: It is by the ID's, not the values. Sorry, I thought I made that apparent. I will edit the post to make that more clear.

Comment: The IDs don't have the same format though: `230621_BGH_03_NOX` vs. `230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 2_NOX`. What part of the IDs should be used for the join?

Comment: That is kind of my problem, they are similar but not exact matches to one another. "Spike 1" and "Spike 2" are QA/QC replicate procedures that use the same base "SampleConc" value (which I am tring to match via the corresponding ID from the "Samples" df) in downstream calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to harmonize the ID columns. We can remove ” SPIKE [0-9]+” from
the `Spike.ID` to get IDs that are compatible with the ID in `Samples`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

spikes_mod <-
  Spikes |>
  mutate(ID = str_remove(Spike.ID, " SPIKE [0-9]+"))

left_join(spikes_mod,
          Samples,
          by = c("ID" = "Sample.ID"))
#>                    Spike.ID SpikeConc                ID SampleConc
#> 1 230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 1_NOX         4 230621_BGH_03_NOX          7
#> 2 230621_BGH_03 SPIKE 2_NOX        11 230621_BGH_03_NOX          7
#> 3 230621_BGH_11 SPIKE 1_NOX        17 230621_BGH_11_NOX         13
#> 4 230621_BGH_11 SPIKE 2_NOX        12 230621_BGH_11_NOX         13
```

Comment: This is somewhat helpful, but I cannot rely on a specific string like "BGH" or even the numbers to determine how to join the dataframes, rather I need to use the fact that the Spike ID's will always follow the same format as the Sample ID's, just with the "SPIKE 1" notation inserted at the end (right before the _NOX). Also, I changed the last Spike ID to be `BGH_11` as you correctly noted.